# Change bindingPath based on Selection in sap.m.Select

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5 and currently, I am trying to understand the meaning and the usage of bindingContext and context.

Let's assume that I have the following files:

*Years.json*

```
{
  "FiscalYear": [
    {
      "Jahr": 2017,
      "JahrID": 2017,
      "AEIst": 400,
      "AEPlan": 200,
      "UEIst": 300,
      "UEPlan": 200,
      "EBITIst": 300,
      "EBITPlan": 400,
      "Umsatzkategorie": [
        {
          "Umsatzkategorie": "ABC",
          "AE": 2
        },
        {
          "Umsatzkategorie": "DEF",
          "AE": 3
        },
        {
          "Umsatzkategorie": "GHI",
          "AE": 6
        },
        {
          "Umsatzkategorie": "XYZ",
          "AE": 8
        }
      ],
      "FiscalYearPeriod": [
        {
          "Monat": "JAN.2017",
          "AEIst": 14,
          "UEIst": 11
        },
        {
          "Monat": "FEB.2017",
          "AEIst": 12,
          "UEIst": 32
        },
        {
          "Monat": "MAR.2017",
          "AEIst": 15,
          "UEIst": 10
        },
        {
          "Monat": "APR.2017",
          "AEIst": 18,
          "UEIst": 9
        },
        {
          "Monat": "MAI.2017",
          "AEIst": 19,
          "UEIst": 5
        },
        {
          "Monat": "JUN.2017",
          "AEIst": 20,
          "UEIst": 12
        },
        {
          "Monat": "JUL.2017",
          "AEIst": 13,
          "UEIst": 14
        },
        {
          "Monat": "AUG.2017",
          "AEIst": 10,
          "UEIst": 13
        },
        {
          "Monat": "SEP.2017",
          "AEIst": 7,
          "UEIst": 15
        },
        {
          "Monat": "OKT.2017",
          "AEIst": 9,
          "UEIst": 18
        },
        {
          "Monat": "NOV.2017",
          "AEIst": 8,
          "UEIst": 7
        },
        {
          "Monat": "DEZ.2017",
          "AEIst": 34,
          "UEIst": 20
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Jahr": 2018,
      "JahrID": 2018,
      "AEIst": 400,
      "AEPlan": 20022222222222,
      "UEIst": 300,
      "UEPlan": 200,
      "EBITIst": 300,
      "EBITPlan": 400,
      "Umsatzkategorie": [
        {
          "Umsatzkategorie": "ABC",
          "AE": 2
        },
        {
          "Umsatzkategorie": "DEF",
          "AE": 3
        },
        {
          "Umsatzkategorie": "GHI",
          "AE": 6
        },
        {
          "Umsatzkategorie": "XYZ",
          "AE": 8
        }
      ],
      "FiscalYearPeriod": [
        {
          "Monat": "JAN.2017",
          "AEIst": 14,
          "UEIst": 11
        },
        {
          "Monat": "FEB.2017",
          "AEIst": 12,
          "UEIst": 32
        },
        {
          "Monat": "MAR.2017",
          "AEIst": 15,
          "UEIst": 10
        },
        {
          "Monat": "APR.2017",
          "AEIst": 18,
          "UEIst": 9
        },
        {
          "Monat": "MAI.2017",
          "AEIst": 19,
          "UEIst": 5
        },
        {
          "Monat": "JUN.2017",
          "AEIst": 20,
          "UEIst": 12
        },
        {
          "Monat": "JUL.2017",
          "AEIst": 13,
          "UEIst": 14
        },
        {
          "Monat": "AUG.2017",
          "AEIst": 10,
          "UEIst": 13
        },
        {
          "Monat": "SEP.2017",
          "AEIst": 7,
          "UEIst": 15
        },
        {
          "Monat": "OKT.2017",
          "AEIst": 9,
          "UEIst": 18
        },
        {
          "Monat": "NOV.2017",
          "AEIst": 8,
          "UEIst": 7
        },
        {
          "Monat": "DEZ.2017",
          "AEIst": 34,
          "UEIst": 20
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

View (just the part I want to change):

```
<Select id="theList" forceSelection="false" change="onListSelect" selectedKey="{years>/FiscalYear/1/JahrID}" width="auto" items="{
                            path: 'years>/FiscalYear',
                            sorter: { path: 'Jahr' }
                        }" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
          <core:Item key="{years>Jahr}" text="{years>JahrID}" />
        </Select>


//... some more stuff

<GenericTile class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout" frameType="TwoByOne" id="idtile" header="Auftragseingang Gesamt" subheader="Aktuell in EUR" press="press">
    <TileContent footer="YTD">
        <content>
            <NumericContent scale="M" indicator="Down" value="{years>/FiscalYear/1/AEPlan}" valueColor="Error" />
        </content>
    </TileContent>
</GenericTile>
```

Controller:

```
onListSelect: function(oEvent) {    
    var selectedItem = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem();    
    var context = selectedItem.getBindingContext("years"); //trying to get the binding path
    console.log(context);
    var oTile = this.getView().byId("idtile");
    //pseudocode:
    //get relevant tile (oTile in this case) and change the binding path of the numeric content value to something else

    oTile.setBindingContext(new sap.ui.model.Context("years", "/years>/FiscalYear/1/AEPlan"));

},
```

What I want to achieve is the following case:

Based on the selected value of `sap.m.Select` I want to adjust the binding path for the mentioned tile.

For example: If its binded to the node 2017 and the users selects 2018 in the select control, the value of the numeric content of the tile should be adjusted to the relevant one from the node 2018.

https://flpportal-p1942326342trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/sites/digidash#dashboard3602-Display
This is an example of what I want to achieve.

Actually I am struggling with the understanding of the bindingContext and bindingPath.

I would really appreciate it, if someone could provide me an example for the mentioned case. Hopefully this will provide a better understanding of that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do ElementBinding, here the documentation

- [Tutorial theory](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/6c7c5c266b534e7ea9a28f861dc515f5)
- [Tutorial demo](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.databinding.13/preview)

I made a snippet selecting a year from a table row here: [bind values of specific array of a json model to a control in sapui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070680/bind-values-of-specific-array-of-a-json-model-to-a-control-in-sapui5/49079092#49079092)

you just need to do the same using the Select 'change' event

#### EDIT

Didn't try it, but I would change this:

```
onListSelect: function(oEvent) {    
    var selectedItem = oEvent.getParameter('selectedItem');
    var sPath = selectedItem.getBindingContext("years").getPath(); //This path will include the index of your selected year (e.g. /FiscalYear/1/)
    this.getView().byId("idtile").bindElement("years>" + sPath);
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to do the element binding at the very begining without doing a selection yet and binding the hardcoded path '/FiscalYear/1/'. Just choose an event in the lifecicle and do elemenet binding with the hardcoded path. For example using onInit

```
onInit: function() {
    this.getView().byId("idtile").bindElement("years>/FiscalYear/1/");
}
```

And make the binding relative in the XML, so it completes the path binded by element binding:

```
<NumericContent scale="M" indicator="Down" value="{years>AEPlan}" valueColor="Error" />
```

Comment: I already tried to configure it with your snippet before I asked the question, the thing is that i am binding here to a path with an already specified index. Based on your snippet and the linked tutorial, I guess I know how it works for an ongoing aggregation binding, but I am confused about how to solve it with changing the index in the path.
And one more thing: what is getParameter function and especially the value "listItem" about?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that you are the same user... The getParameter is a function available in the event object. you can see the parameters of each event in the documentation. for example [this is the docu](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Select/events/change) for sap.m.Select 'change' event. As you can see you can retrieve 'selectedItem' from the event parameters. In the sap.m.List of the other example, the parameter was called 'listItem'

Comment: thanks for that clearance. Sometimes its really hard to understand the docu, maybe just from my perspective. I tried to adjust the settings you have mentioned (or better to say from the example) but the values on the tiles are not changing. could that be possible because of the static binding path? if yes, is there any way to solve that?

Comment: I've just edit my answer. Are you passing the model name when using "bindElement()" ?? Check it, because I think the 'getPath()' returns the path without the model name. I can't test it right now

Comment: iam directly trying this to tomorrow, i guess iam getting a better understanding of that whole thing right now. I owe you at least a beer Rafael! have a good night!

Comment: no problem!! I enjoy it and learn a lot while solving issues :)

Comment: thanks again, i made work. option 2 was the way to go for me. iam defining the binding path now in the controller for each of the controls and then I am able to switch the values by selecting a different item in the select-control. I owe you a beer! ;)